# Create SQL Script to Change Old Database to Current One

Tags: sql, sql-server, create-table

I'm creating the front-end for a project and I made a copy of the back-end database from the company's server and put it on my computer.  I needed to make some changes (a few new tables and two new columns in an existing table) for security roles and other things so I duplicated the copied database and made my changes on the new one.

I want to deploy my project to the company's server now but we need to modify the original back-end database.  I need to generate a SQL script that finds the changes between the old-database and my newer database, which can be run on the old database to create the new tables and columns. The script should retain the data from the old database and NOT add any junk/testing data I made in my new database.

By the way, I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and the old database on the server is on 2005.  I've been looking around for utilities to use and found [tablediff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162843%28SQL.90%29.aspx). However, it looks like it will copy the data and I can't see an argument on the information page to toggle this.

I'm sure it's simple but I'm not really sure how to do this.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: I guess you are looking for something like [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576400/whats-the-best-way-to-diff-two-database-backup-files-with-ms-sql-server-2005)

Comment: @TI thanks for the link.  It was really helpful because it reminded me what new tables I added so I could copy their create statements, and I only added about 3 new columns to existing tables so I could manually write their ALTER TABLE statements.  Probably not the most elegant solution but it's a pretty basic data model I'm working with so it works well.  If you post that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3):

By far the solution I trust most to handle schema comparisons is Red Gate's SQL Compare:

http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/

It has a companion called Data Compare which is designed specifically for data. You can grab the free trial to see if it does what you need in this case.

There are other options as well, for example [SQL Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx) has this functionality, though I haven't tested it to any degree that I could compare feature sets, performance, etc.

I've also blogged about why you want to use a tool and just pay for this functionality, rather than solve it programmatically yourself. The post also mentions a variety of alternatives if budget is a primary blocker:

http://bertrandaaron.wordpress.com/2012/04/20/re-blog-the-cost-of-reinventing-the-wheel/

Comment: Thanks.  The software looks really good but the price is a little high for the scope of this project.  I'll keep it in mind for some of our more complicated models.
Cool blog btw.

Comment: @user1287523 While I have no background about your location, professional situation or project, I strongly suggest that you (or your boss?) heed Aaron's advice and consider the cost of this or another tool vs. the cost of your time. I would be extremely unhappy if someone on my team told me he had 'saved' a few hundred dollars by spending a week evaluating tools or - even worse - building his own. I know that this is obvious advice and may not be welcomed in your situation for 'budget' or 'political' reasons, but that doesn't affect the validity of Aaron's points.

Comment: @Pondlife I completely understand.  In this particular case though, I spent about ~30 minutes of my time getting what I needed using DBComparer, as this project is small.  As I've said we have some more complicated projects with models about 50-60x more complex than the one I've been working on, with older and higher paid employees, and in those cases this SQL Compare tool will be essential.